# How to update main record with ProcessInstanceStep ?

Tags: approval-process

I am attempting to update the main record upon the creation of a new ProcessInstanceStep in the Approval Process. And so I am attempting to go from the ProcessInstanceStep -> ProcessInstance -> Main_Object__c (Project_Request__c)

I have put this trigger together - but now I am getting the error : 'SOject type does not allow triggers: ProcessInstanceStep'

Is there any way I can do this ? Ultimately, I want to pull the ActorID from the latest ProcessInstanceStep and populate a field in the main record ("Current_Approver__c"). If I can do this I will be able to write reports showing the Current Approver of a request.

Is there any way to do this ?

Here is the code, although I don't know if it matters if I won't be able to run it :

```
trigger UpdateProjectRequest on ProcessInstanceStep (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(ProcessInstanceStep child : trigger.new){
        parentIds.add(child.ProcessInstanceID);
    }
    Map<Id,ProcessInstance> ProcessInstanceRecords = new Map<Id,ProcessInstance>([Select TargetObjectID from ProcessInstance where id in :parentIds]);
    Set<Id> TargetObjectIDIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(ProcessInstance ProcessInstanceRecord : ProcessInstanceRecords.values()){
        TargetObjectIDIds.add(ProcessInstanceRecord.TargetObjectID);
    }

    Map<Id,Project_Request__c> TargetObjectIDRecords = new Map<Id,Project_Request__c>([Select id,Latest_ProcessInstanceStep__c from Project_Request__c where id in : TargetObjectIDIds]);

    for(ProcessInstanceStep child : trigger.new){
        if(ProcessInstanceRecords.containsKey(child.ProcessInstanceID) && TargetObjectIDRecords.containsKey(ProcessInstanceRecords.get(child.ProcessInstanceID).TargetObjectID)){
            TargetObjectIDRecords.get(ProcessInstanceRecords.get(child.ProcessInstanceID).TargetObjectID).Latest_ProcessInstanceStep__c = 'Update Value';
        }
    }
    update TargetObjectIDRecords.values;
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: does field update on an approval step allow you to set the approverId into the target object (custom field)? If not, you can set some other field @ approval onto the target object and then the trigger on the target object can read the approval related list to discover the approver's Id

Comment: no, a field update cannot set the approverID to a field on the target object. And I can't set a field on the target object by just doing a re-assign in the approval process, and I need to account for re-assigns (not just approvals or rejects) in order to accurately display the "Current Approver" in the target object. That is why I was trying to trigger off the creation of a new ProcessInstanceStep. This is all way more difficult than it should be.

Comment: Scheduled job on objects not yet approved that query the related list and grab current approver, smashing into the target object-then run reports.   Jobs could run every 5 -60 minutes

Comment: Man, that's so klunky. And I think even if I do it every 5min it will still confuse the users when they re-assign something and wonder why the Current Approver field hasn't updated.